# Umbraco goes crazy after loosing DB connection

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

We use Umbraco v.7.2.6 on multiple nodes.

When Database Server gets reloaded. Umbraco starts pushing infinite amount of sql queries similar to those shown on the image.

The load on the network channels increases by 6 times, and runs into the bandwidth limitation. No need to say our environment starts operate very slow.

The only way to solve the problem is to restore previous backup of the database. This issue happens occasionally and we don't know how to fix it.

What would be the steps to troubleshoot the problem?

[image: umbraco db trace]

Comment: What do you mean by "database gets reloaded". Is this when you restore from a backup?

Comment: Not database, but entire sql-server gets reloaded for maintenance reasons etc.